# SwiftUI - Allow a List item to have both cell tap and button tap

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to have a List that each item supports both cell tap and button tap

Currently, I have the following code, but for some reason, when I tap the `hello` button in each cell, although I do receive the action, but it also triggers the highlight from the background button, when i m tapping the `hello` button, I only want the highlight on the `hello` button, not on the whole cell

I searched everywhere can't really find an answer

Thanks in advance!

```
private enum MenuItem: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    var id: String {
        self.rawValue
    }
    
    case option1
    case option2
    case option3
    case option4
}

private struct MainView: View {
    
    let onSelect: (MenuItem) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("Demo")
                .padding(16)
            List {
                Section("hello") {
                    ForEach(MenuItem.allCases) { item in
                        ZStack {
                            Button("") {
                                print("yes", item)
                            }
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                                Text(item.rawValue).font(.title2)
                                Text("something here").font(.body)
                                Button("Hello") {
                                    print("no", item)
                                }.buttonStyle(BorderedButtonStyle())
                                    
                            }
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            .padding(.top, 10)
                            .padding(.bottom, 10)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.listStyle(.plain)
                
        }.onAppear {
            UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = {
                let view = UIView()
                view.backgroundColor = .blue
                return view
            }()
        }
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView(onSelect: { _ in })
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Basically we need a custom button style in this situation (because automatic one is handled by List and gives observed behavior).

Here is main part. Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
    Button("") {
        print("yes", item)
    }
    .buttonStyle(MyStyle())    // << here !!

// ...

    struct MyStyle: ButtonStyle {
        func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
            configuration.label
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .background(   // highlight on row tap
                    configuration.isPressed ? Color.secondary : Color.clear
                )
        }
    }
```

[Complete test code on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestTwoButtonsInList.swift)